# Android: How can I get device hardware information with adb command?

Tags: android, kernel, hardware

I would like to know how to retrieve specific hardware information, for example, from the camera, using an adb command. I would like to know if its possible to retrieve hardware ID or Physical device object name for example, to store these values.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sdk:

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk
```

Complete list:

```
adb shell getprop
```

Through the package manager:

```
adb shell pm list features
```

To retrieve detailed information about the camera

```
adb shell dumpsys media.camera
```

Comment: One question, as I don't have installed adb in my machine yet (missing android phone). This command would display device information about the android phone/tablet. But will it also return info regarding hardware parts like the camera? if so, could you provide an example of the hardware information output? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Yes it will provide some properties of hardware like camera...if you want to retrieve detailed info about camera use this one **adb shell dumpsys media.camera**

Answer (score 0):

adb shell getprop 
replace x with the prop. you want

Comment: "Replace x with the prop you want"? What x?